# Commit hook in JOOQ

Tags: java, sql, transactions, hook, jooq

I've been using JOOQ in backend web services for a while now. In many of these services, after persisting data to the database (or better said, after successfully committing data), we usually want to write some messages to Kafka about the persisted records so that other services know of these events.

What I'm essentially looking for is: Is there a way for me to register a post-commit hook or callback with JOOQ's `DSLContext` object, so I can run some code when a transaction successfully commits?

I'm aware of the `ExecuteListener` and `ExecuteListenerProvider` interfaces, but as far as I can tell the `void end(ExecuteContext ctx)` method (which is supposedly for end of lifecycle uses) is not called when committing the transaction. It is called after every query though.

Here's an example:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("<url>", "<user>", "<pass>");
    connection.setAutoCommit(false);

    DSLContext context = DSL.using(connection, SQLDialect.POSTGRES_9_5);
    context.transaction(conf -> {
        conf.set(new DefaultExecuteListenerProvider(new DefaultExecuteListener() {
            @Override
            public void end(ExecuteContext ctx) {
                System.out.println("End method triggered.");
            }
        }));

        DSLContext innerContext = DSL.using(conf);
        System.out.println("Pre insert.");
        innerContext.insertInto(...).execute();
        System.out.println("Post insert.");
    });

    connection.close();
}
```

Which always seems to print:

```
Pre insert.
End method triggered.
Post insert.
```

Making me believe this is not intended for commit hooks.

Is there perhaps a JOOQ guru that can tell me if there is support for commit hooks in JOOQ? And if so, point me in the right direction?

Comment: Try combining `TransactionProvider`, `RecordListener`, and `ExecuteListener`. You could capture c/u/d records in a thread local and either discard or publish depending on the completion of the outermost transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`ExecuteListener`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ExecuteListener.html) SPI is listening to the lifecycle of a *single query execution*, i.e. of this:

```
innerContext.insertInto(...).execute();
```

This isn't what you're looking for. Instead, you should implement your own [`TransactionProvider`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/TransactionProvider.html) (possibly delegating to jOOQ's [`DefaultTransactionProvider`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DefaultTransactionProvider.html)). You can then implement any logic you want prior to the actual commit logic.

Note that jOOQ 3.9 will also provide a new `TransactionListener` SPI ([see #5378](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5378)) to facilitate this.

Comment: It might be a bit messy to get the `TransactionProvider` from the `DSLContext`, cast it, and then attach a callback, but I've managed to get it to work properly. Thanks a lot Lukas! Btw, looking forward to the new `TransactionListener` in 3.9, but I noticed you can only set listeners. Why not allow adding them at runtime?

Comment: @MichaeldeJong Yes, that callback solution will work nicely. Why do you think you won't be able to add listeners at runtime?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong (probably), but looking at [the code](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/commit/4e1f458e6c1f0e1e7e695f84890956fb8cc30ecd#diff-5b0bc82019c25f8bf90f60d2b2177b17R806), every time you're calling this method it replaces whatever was previously set. I know it's about the `TransactionListenerProvider` instead of the `TransactionListener`, but if you wanted to add/register one during a transaction, you'd need to fetch whatever providers are registered first, add your new one to a resized array, and call the `set(TransactionListenerProvider...)` method right?

Comment: Your own `TransactionListenerProvider` can do whatever you want it to do, including listening to some event that you add/register during a transaction... Nothing in jOOQ's API prevents you from overriding anything at any time. You just have to implement your own mechanism